# X axis values for histogram

Tags: javascript, d3.js, histogram

How should one define values range for X axis?

I've took example which used decimal values in range `0 to 1`, and this clearly doesn't work for greater numbers.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.bar rect {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.bar text {
  fill: #fff;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

// var data = d3.range(1000).map(d3.randomBates(10));
var data = [1321017167, 1421017167, 1421017167, 1421017167, 1521017167, 1521017167];

var formatCount = d3.format(",.0f");

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 30},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([0, width]);

var bins = d3.histogram()
    .domain(x.domain())
    .thresholds(x.ticks(20))
    (data);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(bins, function(d) { return d.length; })])
    .range([height, 0]);

var bar = g.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(bins)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x0) + "," + y(d.length) + ")"; });

bar.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 1)
    .attr("width", x(bins[0].x1) - x(bins[0].x0) - 1)
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.length); });

bar.append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".75em")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("x", (x(bins[0].x1) - x(bins[0].x0)) / 2)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) { return formatCount(d.length); });

g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the domain of a linear scale is `[0, 1]`. You just copied that code from Mike Bostock without changing the domain. In his original code the domain is, coincidentally, the default domain, but in your code you have to define it:

```
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .domain(d3.extent(data))//domain here
```

Here I'm using `d3.extent`, but you can use any other array you want.

Here is your code with that change only:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.bar rect {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.bar text {
  fill: #fff;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

// var data = d3.range(1000).map(d3.randomBates(10));
var data = [1321017167, 1421017167, 1421017167, 1421017167, 1521017167, 1521017167];

var formatCount = d3.format(",.0f");

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 30},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .domain(d3.extent(data))

var bins = d3.histogram()
    .domain(x.domain())
    .thresholds(x.ticks(20))
    (data);
    
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(bins, function(d) { return d.length; })])
    .range([height, 0]);

var bar = g.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(bins)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x0) + "," + y(d.length) + ")"; });

bar.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 1)
    .attr("width", x(bins[0].x1) - x(bins[0].x0) - 1)
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.length); });

bar.append("text")
    .attr("dy", ".75em")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("x", (x(bins[0].x1) - x(bins[0].x0)) / 2)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) { return formatCount(d.length); });

g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

</script>
```

PS: You'll have to adjust the horizontal position of the rectangles.

Comment: Tnx, I wasn't aware of defaults.